# SharePoint 2013 and WebApi

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, asp.net, httpmodules

I would like to use ASP.NET WebApi inside a SharePoint 2013 farm solution.

I know it is not supported out-of-the-box, but I found [SignalR can be run by means of a simple HttpModule](http://melcher.it/2012/12/signalr-in-sharepoint-2013-the-real-time-web-is-coming/), so I was wondering whether a similar appoach could be used.

Thanks in advance, Rich

Cross Post @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16447751/sharepoint-2013-and-asp-net-webapi

**Update 1**
I wrote a module to map HttpRoutes similar to the one in the referenced article:

- When *turned OFF*, I get a **404 - Not Found** (which is OK)
- When *turned ON*, I get a **401 - Unauthorized** from SharePoint

No matter which controller&action I pick.

**My guess is WebApi should be integrated somehow with SharePoint security**.
*Tips?*

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement a virtual path provider like written in my blog post mentioned above? 
If not, you need one.

Edit: You can see the sourcecode here: https://spsignalr.codeplex.com/

Comment: Can you please add more details about how to do what you propose?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured out how to host a custom WebApi in SharePoint, or determined if it's even possible at all. You can host a custom WCF REST service in SharePoint 2013 though. I have a video walkthrough of the process on YouTube.

[Building a SharePoint-Hosted WCF Service](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rje25vBQEDA)